# rust chrono Utc add year, month using Add triats or better way

Tags: date, datetime, rust, utc, rust-chrono

```
// Cargo.toml
chrono = { version = "0.4", features = ["serde", "rustc-serialize"] }
```

```
let mut date: DateTime<Utc> = DateTime::default();

date += Duration::years(1000); // no Duration::years()
date += Duration::months(1000); // no Duration::months()
date += Duration::days(1000); 
date += Duration::hours(1000); 
date += Duration::minutes(1000);
date += Duration::seconds(1000);
```

```
date = date.with_year(date.year() + 1000).unwrap(); // Ok
date = date.with_month(date.month() + 1000).unwrap(); // if date.with_month() parameter is over 12, panick
```

what is best way that calculate Utc in rust chrono??

Comment: what do you mean by "calculate UTC"? also, note that "year" or "month" are ambiguous quantities; neither of the two has a fixed number of days.

Comment: Utc means DateTime<Utc> variable(in src, let mut date). The meaning of year, month intened is ,like Duration::days, Duration::hours, a structure that can be added to DateTime<Utc>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a month can have anywhere from 28 to 31 days it's not a `Duration`, to still be able to work with them you can use the [`Months`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/struct.Months.html) abstraction:

```rust
use chrono::Months;
date = date + Months::new(1000);
```